# Convert file to array and explode with comma

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to convert my rpt file to array. The file is divided with commas. Of course that's easy part. The second thing I need to convert it into multidimensional array, which probably is also easy but I got stuck in it. I need to make it that **each line of the file will be next row**.
I'm looking in my head but I don't know how to solve it.
I hope you'll help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try the explode function of php?

Comment: Yes I did it, but I still have problem with dividing my file that each line will be other row.

Comment: can you give a sample output of your file? I mean to say the string which you are explode.

Comment: By now I have something like this: `$contents = file_get_contents($path);
      $pollfields = explode(',', $contents);
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($pollfields);
        echo '</pre>';`

Comment: I want to know the string. You are given all php codes. I need the value of $contents.

Comment: Okay, look at the image.

Comment: you can read a file line by line and explode each. example of how to read [at](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.fgets.php)

Comment: Please, look again on the question.

Comment: Did you have a space between first line and second line?

Comment: Yes, I have <cr> at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = file($path);
foreach($contents as &$row){
  $row = explode(",",$row);
}
```

`file()` reads the file into an array, one line is one array element.

Comment: It's not what I am looking for could you look at the topic again? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This is exactly what you said you want.

Comment: Not exactly, because now I have array with rows of the file and I also need to list the column of the rows like in picture above.

Comment: Okay I've solved it out, with your code but a little bit editing it. Thanks!